# Titanium - converting mobile application project to web application project

Tags: web-applications, titanium, mobile-application

I have got an existing mobile application source files for Titanium Studio project, and it's running fine. Can I convert this to web application (website/ mobile-website) by making small adjustments?

In Phonegap project, it's really easy by accessing 'www' folder. But here, titanium source files are in XML format. So, is it even possible to convert it? Or, I'll have to do it start from scratch?

Comment: It should be possible by simply enable it as a web app in the tiapp.xml. Maybe you have to adapt your xmls.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the tiapp.xml and select **Mobile Web** under **Deployment Targets** then you will be able to export your project as a HTML/JS project and upload it to publish it as a website.

Probably you will need to make some adjustments as not all the features are compatible with mobile web.

Comment: i selected "mobile web" and when i run it it claims i have an error... [ERROR] :  ENOENT, no such file or directory 'C:\Blahblah\build\mobileweb\titanium\Ti\API.js'